# Node js separate service File

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a node file in this i want to separate service

```
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/v1/config', function (req, res) {
  var config = require('../service/config');
  config.getAllConfig().then(function (data) {
    res.send(data);
  });
```

In service config file

```
var config  = {};
config.getAllConfig = function (){
  return some_json;
};
module.exports = config;
```

But it throwing 500 internal server error.How to separate the service in node js

Comment: Your `config.getAllConfig` is not a promise so you can't use .then

Comment: Still the same issue @rkmax

Comment: are you using module.exports = router at the end of the separate service and called correctly in your main file? could you please post the error you got from the console

Answer (score 1):

You won't be having a `then()` method since you are not returning a promise so you have to remove that.

I've done a quick test, which works just fine:

main.js:

```
var config = require('./test');
console.log(config.getAllConfig());
```

test.js:

```
var config  = {};
config.getAllConfig = function (){
  return "Test";
};
module.exports = config;
```